# Как сделать массив со ссылками на enum?

Tags: c#

Привет всем!
Есть массив к которому периодически обращаются извне. Этот массив инициализируется 1 раз и больше его менять нельзя. Например такой массив:

static(или const) KeyCode[] arr = {v1, v2, v3, v4};

Пока не знаю статиком или константным его сделать, но суть в том, что менять его содержимое так: arr[i]=x; нельзя. Однако переменные v могут менять своё содержимое и это должно быть видно через массив. KeyCode - это enum, v1-4 тоже enum-ы. Хожу воокруг да около, в чем проблема: этот массив берет и копирует в себя содержимое enum, то есть в нем копии переменных, а не сами исходные переменные. Если arr был бы классом, то все было бы как надо: можно было бы не заниматься присвоением arr[i] нового значения чтобы изменение содержимого его переменных можно было увидеть через массив.
Как можно такое провернуть?

Comment: "переменные v могут менять своё содержимое" - что это значит?

Comment: Это значит, что если бы я сохранил ссылку на участок памяти какой-то из v, то обращяясь к этому участку памяти всегда имел бы разное содержимое.

Comment: давно не писал на шарп, но вроде бы можно сделать так private static List<KeyCode> arr = new List<KeyCode> { KeyCode.One, KeyCode.Two };
 public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<KeyCode> Array = new ReadOnlyCollection<KeyCode>(arr);

Comment: Это чтоб не менять. Не понятно что вы хотите менять за содержимое. Вроде бы изменять енам во время выполнения нельзя, или сложно. Думаю енам в вашем случае не подойдет

Comment: А можно массив сделать массивом на указатели на разные функции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему, вы хотите, чтобы элементы вашей коллекции можно было изменять внутри вашего класса, но не снаружи.

Это проще всего сделать так:

```
class Test
{
    private readonly KeyCode[] arr = { KeyCode.A, KeyCode.B, KeyCode.C, KeyCode.D };
    public ReadOnlyCollection<KeyCode> Arr { get; }

    public Test()
    {
        Arr = Array.AsReadOnly(arr);
    }
}
```

Теперь изменения, сделанные через `arr`, будут видны через `Arr`:

```
Console.WriteLine(Arr[0]); // A
arr[0] = KeyCode.Z;
Console.WriteLine(Arr[0]); // Z
//Arr[0] = KeyCode.A;    // <-- не скомпилируется
```

Comment: Спасибо, сам тоже примерно к этому же  решению пришёл.